# Getting 404 resource not found in jersey uploading a file

Tags: java, jersey, pom.xml

I am developing jersey web service to upload file.I have written the code for this but whenever I click on the submit button of `WelcomeFile.jsp` to upload the file it throws an error 404 resource not found.

I don't know where I am wrong in this code Please help me improve it by doing.

Thanks in advance.

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Rest</display-name>

    <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/ViewPages/WelcomeFile.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>Rest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net Repository for Maven</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

WelcomeFile.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Welcome File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload with Jersey</h1>

    <form action="file/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

       <p>
        Select a file : <input type="file" name="file" size="45" />
       </p>

       <input type="submit" value="Upload It" />
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

UploadFileService.java

```
package serviceServer;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import com.sun.jersey.core.header.FormDataContentDisposition;
import com.sun.jersey.multipart.FormDataParam;

@Path("/file")
public class UploadFileService {
    @POST
    @Path("/upload")
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    public Response uploadFile(
        @FormDataParam("file") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        @FormDataParam("file") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

        System.out.println("hi inside server");
        String uploadedFileLocation = "d://uploaded/" + fileDetail.getFileName();

        // save it
        writeToFile(uploadedInputStream, uploadedFileLocation);

        String output = "File uploaded to : " + uploadedFileLocation;

        return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();

    }

    // save uploaded file to new location
    private void writeToFile(InputStream uploadedInputStream,
        String uploadedFileLocation) {

        try {
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(
                    uploadedFileLocation));
            int read = 0;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];

            out = new FileOutputStream(new File(uploadedFileLocation));
            while ((read = uploadedInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1) {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi anyone is there to help me?

Comment: You should register `UploadFileService` resource in web.xml.

You can see: https://blog.dejavu.sk/2013/11/19/registering-resources-and-providers-in-jersey-2/